# Why doesn't http://stack.exchange redirect to stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I noticed that there's a .exchange TLD and immediately tried to access http://stack.exchange/ but it's not registered. I was wondering why not? It's perfect!

Comment: Because it costs money?

Comment: [it is registered](https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=stack.exchange)

Comment: If we're into fancy TLDs now, there's [stackexchange.network](https://www.enom.com/domains/search-results?query=stackexchange.network) which is still available. But the first reaction to seeing a site with familiar name but unusual TLD is probably "phishing or malware".

Answer (score 1):

Because the domain belongs to an UK company that probably wants big money from Stack Overflow Inc. to hand over the domain. And that is not going to happen...

SO is a company that doesn't just wildly spend tons on web addresses. They try to be as cost-effective as possible, both for their business model and to have enough funds to do more important things.